# How can I test Node.js code to the browser?

Tags: php, node.js

I used to use PHP in my projects and MySQL of course, but I'm starting a course to Node.js right now and I really don't understand how it works. In PHP all I ever needed was an Apache as localhost and MySQL.

But when I use Node.js, what do I need ? The main question is how and where I can implement and write Node.js code and how I test it on the browser like I used to do in PHP?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately [questions asking for tutorials are off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and should be closed. Stack Overflow is a [Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) website for specific programming questions.

Answer (score 1):

Node.js is a runtime for JavaScript code that is specifically *not* run in the browser. To execute JavaScript in Node.js, you simply run Node.js from the command line and supply your JavaScript source file as an argument.

```
node myFile.js
```

This will execute whatever is in `myFile.js`. This file could look like the following:

```
let myVar = 1;
for (myVar; myVar < 5; myVar++) {
    console.log(myVar);
}
```

This would print the following to the command line, when run:

```
1234
```